# Compile with -fopenmp in netbeans configured with g++ and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, openmp

I am trying to configure my netbeans to work on my parallel programming C++ code. I could compile that code using command line (cygwin) but now for further debugging and coding more complex things I wanna move to some IDE and selected neatbeans to do my task. Can someone suggest me how to add `-fopenmp` to compile my application once I click build my application button in netbeans. (have already configured GCC and G++ with netbeans_. Below is the error I gets if I build my code using netbeans:

```
    cd 'D:\University\PARALLEL\ParallelTesting'
C:\dev_softwares\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/University/PARALLEL/ParallelTesting'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/paralleltesting.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/University/PARALLEL/ParallelTesting'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/paralleltesting build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/d/University/PARALLEL/ParallelTesting/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/cygdrive/d/University/PARALLEL/ParallelTesting/main.cpp:26:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `omp_get_thread_num'
/cygdrive/d/University/PARALLEL/ParallelTesting/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
/cygdrive/d/University/PARALLEL/ParallelTesting/main.cpp:32:(.text+0x34): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `omp_get_num_threads'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/paralleltesting.exe' failed
```

p.s: new to the world of Parallel programming and already configured gcc with netbeans.

[image: My gcc configuration FYI]

[image: Versions]

My test parallel code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
int nthreads, tid;

/* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
  {

  /* Obtain thread number */
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

  /* Only master thread does this */
  if (tid == 0) 
    {
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    }

  }  /* All threads join master thread and disband */

}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. updated my question, added my test parallel program.

Comment: There is a place to add additional compiler flags: [see here](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-51329.html)

Comment: Cool, thanks it worked.

Comment: @Hristolliev I reckon this setting is for per project. Can we have this setting as default for all the projects in netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what I did and it worked. Thanks to @Hristolliev.

> If it is a managed C/C++ project, then compiler options can be
>   specified  in project properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler ->
>   Additional Options.

[image]